# LEFT JOIN FETCH in Hibernate with subquery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I get error
`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:`
its my query on HQL

```
 @Query(value = "FROM RateValue r "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.status "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.rate "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.parameterValues v "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH v.status "
            + "LEFT JOIN (select * from parameter p "
            + "WHERE p.status_id = 1) p on p.id = v.parameter.id "
            + "WHERE r.status_id= 1 AND r.rate.id=:rateId AND r.branchValue in :branchCodes"
```

I try to change my query which works in mysql

```
select *
FROM rates.rate_value r
  left join rates.status s on s.id = r.status_id
  left join rates.rate ra on ra.id = r.rate_id
  LEFT JOIN rates.rate_parameter_value rrp on r.id = rrp.rate_value_id
  LEFT join rates.parameter_value pV on rrp.parameter_value_id = pV.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from
                rates.parameter p
              WHERE (p.status_id = 1 ) ) p on p.id=pV.parameter_id
```

Can anyone know, how to correctly write HQL query with this SQL?

Comment: `from Parameter`, the P should be uppercase.

Comment: or better, `LEFT JOIN rates.parameter p ON p.id=pV.parameter_id AND  p.status_id = 1`

Comment: i`m getting yhsi error:   ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "status7_"

Comment: What the exception do you receive when executing the JPQL that you made? Please, share the entire stack trace of the error. Also, try to change `select *` to `select p` on the subquery.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 172 [FROM kz.sanscrit.cbs.rates.domain.rates.RateValue r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.status LEFT JOIN FETCH r.rate LEFT JOIN FETCH r.parameterValues v LEFT